# D3.js - Is the "svg:" in "svg:rect" a must?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

For example:

```
svg.append("svg:rect");
```

1. What if I drop "svg:"? It seems to work without "svg:". Any potential problems for dropping it?
2. Is "svg:" a d3 specific thing or it is generally required when svg
   elements are used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the d3.js [`append()` documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#append)

> The name may be specified either as a constant string or as a function that returns the DOM element to append. When the name is specified as a string, it may have a namespace prefix of the form "namespace:tag". For example, "svg:text" will create a "text" element in the SVG namespace. By default, D3 supports svg, xhtml, xlink, xml and xmlns namespaces. Additional namespaces can be registered by adding to d3.ns.prefix. **If no namespace is specified, then the namespace will be inherited from the enclosing element; or, if the name is one of the known prefixes, the corresponding namespace will be used (for example, "svg" implies "svg:svg").**

So namespaces are (in most cases) optional since [this](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/commit/11c1e7a906409d7748dec3193768c58739b26e45) commit.

Answer (score 1):

The `svg:` part specifies the namespace to be used for the element. In particular, `svg:rect` means that the `rect` should be interpreted in the SVG namespace. This is relevant because not all types of elements exist in all namespaces (e.g. HTML does not have `rect`s).

You do not normally need to specify this explicitly in recent versions of D3 as the namespace is derived from the context. In some cases, you do need to specify it to have the document interpreted properly. A notable example is when using `foreignObject` in SVG, which allows you to embed non-SVG content, see [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1424037). Here it is necessary to specify `xhtml` as the namespace for the appended `body` element as the context is SVG and it would be interpreted incorrectly.